# What metrics exist to compare image feature vectors except least squares?

Tags: image-processing, classification, metrics, similarity, feature-extraction

I have elongation, solidity and [Hu Moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment) features that represent a set of 150 images.
I would like to know what are typical metrics to make comparison with these feature vectors without using least squares or a Support Vector Machine (because I do not know at which class they belong).

Comment: Isn't it only for text mining? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity

Comment: No it isn't. http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=cosine+similarity+computer+vision